# What option will generate fewer aquifers in world gen?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I am facing an aquifer at every conceivable location it seems. I finally figured out how to tunnel through on a freezing map, but I don't want to spend so much time above ground. My dwarves need their tunnels.

Comment: As a side note, you can tunnel through on a non-freezing map as well by dropping large sections of above layers into the aquifer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

3 Options:

The Lazy Newb Pack way:
Just click the Aquifers button after running lazy newb pack.exe

[Changing WorldGen Settings:](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=54323.0)
Courtesy of Chrissi from the bay 12 forums

> To actually answer the question.... yes, you can render a world with
>   significantly less aquifers (I have done it) by increasing the minimum
>   elevation in the parameters.  Try 20 or 40 or something.  It also
>   reduces oceans, but oceans are what cause aquifers in the first place.

Obviously this has other side effects on world gen like making the world more mountainous and making oceans smaller/nonexistent depending on how high the minimum elevation is. There is no option to just turn off Aquifers in the advanced mapgen, although I believe some mods do have that option.

[Editing the raws](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2012:Aquifer#The_modding_method):

> Text editor (All operating systems) Find the files in Dwarf
>   Fortress/raw/objects (new world) or Dwarf
>   Fortress/data/save/regionNN/raw/objects (already saved world). Open
>   the three files with a text editor (e.g. Notepad).
>   (inorganic_stone_layer.txt, inorganic_stone_mineral.txt, and
>   inorganic_stone_soil.txt) Use Edit->Replace, and replace [AQUIFER]
>   with (AQUIFER). (Use 'Replace All'). To restore the tags later, do the
>   same in reverse. (Replacing (AQUIFER) with [AQUIFER]).