# Dwarf Fortress: Cannot generate ideal Terrifying biomes

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I want to embark on a Terrifying biome that have the following traits:

- some woods
- moderate foliage
- no aquifer
- deep + shallow metals
- half mountains (to settle in) and half open space (to explore)
- small river so I can go fishing
- temperate weather
- Terrifying biome should not be too dominating on the map since I want other to encounter civs too.
- lots of monsters and animals

But I can't get the map to generate this criteria. I set savage tiles to be `8x8`, min savage `100`. But this ends up with the map gen saying it can't produce any map based on my config. I've tried tweaking this, but I've pretty much defaulted back to `Large Island` since I can't generate a map.

Does anyone have a world map that I can import that will have all these things? Or what are the optimal settings for generating this biome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I am not an expert on [advanced map generation](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Advanced_world_generation), but setting the **Minimum Savagery** to 100 means that every tile in the whole world is at 100 savagery because it doesn't get any higher than that. That breaks the **Minimum Number of Low/Mid-Savagery Squares** constraint in the world generator, as well as your own constraint on not having that biome be too overwhelming.

What has worked for me in similar circumstances is to increase, not the minimum, but the variance. That way you have more areas with at least some of the desired stuff in them.

If you do increase the variance on, say, savagery, you will also need to increase the the **Maximum Number of Subregions**. Otherwise you will get map rejections because there are too many subregions. The downside that I am aware of to increasing this number is that it may increase world gen time and increase save size because the program has to keep track of more locations.

The metals can be encouraged by decreasing the **Mineral Scarcity** option.

Aquifers are tricky. The wiki article on [aquifers](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Aquifer) says that they appear more often in low elevation areas near bodies of water, like rivers. I haven't had any luck in controlling how often they appear. However, If they cover only part of your embark site then you might be able to dig around them.

Temperate weather description is based on temperature. Temperature is determined mostly by latitude and elevation. So in one pole maps areas near the middle of the map will be more likely to be temperate. If you set the **Pole** option you can affect that. I have not experimented with exactly how, but setting the option to no poles may well give you a more temperate world, or at least a more consistent one. You can also limit the temperature ranges somewhat with the **Minimum/Maximum Temperature** options.

For plants and animals you would want to have more rainfall. Perhaps increasing the **Minimum Rainfall** option. Any time you increase a **Minimum whatever** option you need to go and mess with the **Minimum Number of Low-Whatever Squares** option as well, otherwise your worlds will be rejected a lot. Also savagery affects the kinds of animals present. The wiki article of [savagery](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Surroundings#Savage) says that high savagery biomes have more kinds of animals and are the only ones with giant animals. Since you wanted high savagery anyway, this should work out just fine.

You will still have to generate a lot of maps, though, for something that specific. If you are willing to read up there is an advanced feature (that I haven't used) called the [world painter](http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:World_painter) available which can help you get sites more to your liking.

I hope something in here helps.

Comment: He could modify and remove aquifers, I've done this in the past as they are dang annoying. http://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php/DF2014:Aquifer#Text_editor_.28All_operating_systems.29

Comment: That would indeed work. I just didn't consider it because I don't let myself edit the raws. No reason why anyone else shouldn't though unless they decide to limit themselves.

Comment: I just found a question about reducing aquifer creation frequency http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129046/what-option-will-generate-fewer-aquifers-in-world-gen